# Why "if empty" is not working when showing results from a search

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was creating a search engine in order to retrieve some data from an MySQL.

I don't know why when I leave the field empty, it still showing **all the content of the database table**.

Any guesses?

Thank you, and sorry about the messy code.

Here's the code: https://codeshare.io/Gbr9W6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIKE clause is used instead of `=` when you want to find something  similar rather  than finding the exact thing. Example:

***if you want to find the firstname Ray***,

```
SELECT first_name from users WHERE firstname = "Ray";
```

**If you want to find the firstname which contains ray,**

```
SELECT first_name from users WHERE firstname LIKE "%ray%";
```

Now in your case, since the firstname is empty, the query becomes

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE '%%'
```

so it matches everything and returns all the values.

**Code Correction:**
So you could do the following to your code, if you dont  want to retrieve all the values when the first name is empty

```
if(!empty($firstname))
{
    $firstname = "%".$firstname."%";
}
```

and change this code to

```
$statement->execute(array(
    ':firstname' => $firstname
));
```

This will not fetch any results when the firstname submitted is empty as

> LIKE clause is equal to WHERE clause when used without '%'

.

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

If `$firstname` is empty then SQL query becomes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE firstname LIKE '%%'
```

`%` is a wildcard so it matches everything. If you don't want that, you need to check if `$firstname` is empty before performing the query.